# How angular pass params to express?

Tags: angularjs, express

In my project(using angular),I wanna export a excel from some page. The project use websocket, all query will send to it, after query it will have the result data to fill the page.

I use expressjs for routing.when someone come to '/excel' page, and he add some condition for query.after the query,I can export  excel to file.The problem is how can I pass the params to the express.for instance

```
xxxx:3030/excel?id=1&starttime=xxx&endtime=xxx&name=someperson


app.get('/excel', function(req,res){
    // data....
    // when I got data, I can output the xlsx file.
})
```

I'm thinking about passing the HASH to express, and use websocket's instance to query data.will it work? and how can I passing HASH to express?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: What information do you need to pass? Why don't you want to use a POST request?

Comment: you can use `req.query` inside `app.get`

Comment: @doodeec Do not need to pass it to express?

Comment: I assume you are using `$http.get`, so you just add params object as a second parameter inside that function - like `$http.get('/somepage', {params: {id: 'abc1'}})` will produce GET request to url `/somepage?id=abc1` and in express `app.get('/somepage', fn(req,res){ console.log(req.query.id) })`

Comment: @doodeec I get the params by use `req.query`  :)